# Bootstrap 4 MultiLevel Dropdown

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Qual a maneira mais fácil de colocar um dropdown de vários níveis na minha navbar feita com **Bootstrap 4**? Tentei com alguns métodos na internet, mas todos usam por `ul`, já a minha navbar usa `div`'s.

Exemplo:

[image: Exemplo de um dropdown com vários níveis]

```css
.navbar-icon-top .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
  position: relative;
  width: 36px;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.navbar-icon-top .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.navbar-icon-top .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
  top: 3px;
  line-height: 12px;
}

.navbar-icon-top .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
  top: -10px;
}

@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    margin: 2px auto 4px auto;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-sm .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
    top: -7px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    margin: 2px auto 4px auto;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
    top: -7px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    margin: 2px auto 4px auto;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-lg .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
    top: -7px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 70px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .nav-link > i {
    display: block;
    width: 48px;
    margin: 2px auto 4px auto;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 24px;
  }

  .navbar-icon-top.navbar-expand-xl .navbar-nav .nav-link > i > .badge {
    top: -7px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>SGW - Sistema Gestor de Workflows</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Sistema Gestor de Workflows">
        <meta name="author" content="Foxx Haztec">
        <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./content/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!--Normalize/Reset CSS-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./content/normalize.css">
        <!--Font Awesome-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./content/font-awesome.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./content/index/index.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-icon-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foxx Haztec</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
                        <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-bezier-curve">
                        <!-- <span class="badge badge-danger">11</span> -->
                        </i>
                        SGI
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">
                        <i class="fas fa-laptop">
                        <!-- <span class="badge badge-warning">11</span> -->
                        </i>
                        Ti
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-piggy-bank">
                        <!-- <span class="badge badge-primary">11</span> -->
                        </i>
                        Financeiro
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        <i class="fas fa-user">
                        <!-- <span class="badge badge-primary">11</span> -->
                        </i>
                        Olá, usuario!
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sair</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!--jQuery-->
        <script src="./scripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <!--jQuery Validate-->
        <script src="./scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <!--Bootstrap JS-->
        <script src="./scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hudson, pode ser mais específico na sua dúvida?

Comment: @LeandroAlfredo Editei com uma imagem de exemplo.

Comment: boa agora ficou mais fácil, vou trabalhar num exemplo aqui pra vc

Comment: Se alguém precisar para o **Bootstrap 3** aqui tem o link de uma resposta com opção https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398327/não-estou-conseguindo-inserir-submenus-no-menu-dropdown/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hudson, segue o que você precisa.

Coloquei um exemplo com mais dois níveis abaixo para caso vc precisar já ter aonde encontrar. Abraço

```css
.navbar .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar .dropdown-menu a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item.active,
.navbar .dropdown-item:active {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.navbar .dropdown-item:focus,
.navbar .dropdown-item:hover {
  color: #16181b;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .navbar .dropdown-toggle:not(.nav-link)::after {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin-left: .5em;
    vertical-align: 0;
    border-bottom: .3em solid transparent;
    border-top: .3em solid transparent;
    border-left: .3em solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
    
        <title>Bootstrap NavBar Menu Dropdowns - Bootsnipp.com</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.alert = function(){};
            var defaultCSS = document.getElementById('bootstrap-css');
            function changeCSS(css){
                if(css) $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+ css +'" type="text/css" />'); 
                else $('head > link').filter(':first').replaceWith(defaultCSS); 
            }
            $( document ).ready(function() {
              var iframe_height = parseInt($('html').height()); 
              window.parent.postMessage( iframe_height, 'https://bootsnipp.com');
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark mb-4" role="navigation">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap 4 NavBar</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="http://fontenele.github.io/bootstrap-navbar-dropdowns/" target="_blank">Github</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1">
                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 1</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1.1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1">
                                <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 1.1</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1-1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown1.1.1</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown1-1-1">
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 1.1.1</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2">
                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2 A</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2 B</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2 C</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2.1</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-1">
                                <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1 A</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1 B</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1 C</a></li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2-1-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2.1.1</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-1-1">
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.1 A</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.1 B</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.1 C</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li class="dropdown-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2-1-2" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown2.1.2</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown2-1-2">
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.2 A</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.2 B</a></li>
                                        <li class="dropdown-item" href="#"><a>Action 2.1.2 C</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <main role="main" class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
            <h1>Bootstrap 4 NavBar</h1>
            <p class="lead text-info">NavBar with too many childs.</p>
        </div>
    </main> <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('.navbar .dropdown-item').on('click', function (e) {
            var $el = $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle');
            var $parent = $el.offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
            $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');
    
            if (!$parent.parent().hasClass('navbar-nav')) {
                if ($parent.hasClass('show')) {
                    $parent.removeClass('show');
                    $el.next().removeClass('show');
                    $el.next().css({"top": -999, "left": -999});
                } else {
                    $parent.parent().find('.show').removeClass('show');
                    $parent.addClass('show');
                    $el.next().addClass('show');
                    $el.next().css({"top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4});
                }
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
    
        $('.navbar .dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
            $(this).find('li.dropdown').removeClass('show open');
            $(this).find('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show open');
        });
    
    });
     </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Se alguém precisar para o **Bootstrap 3** aqui tem o link de uma resposta com opção https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/398327/não-estou-conseguindo-inserir-submenus-no-menu-dropdown/